# Mostrar imagen en Picturebox desde SQL

Tags: c#

Guardé la imagen usando el `MemoryStream` y la trato de extraer convirtiéndola nuevamente en Imagen usando:

```
byte[] datos = new byte[]; 
Datos = (byte[])row[campo imagen];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(datos);
Picturebox.Image = Image.Fromstream(ms);
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui es como inserto la imagen a la base de datos,

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes, ¿hay algún problema con tu código?, si te arroja algún error sería bueno que lo añadas a tu pregunta.

Comment: Este es el error que me muestra ArgumentExceptiom esa unhandled , me dice que el parámetro no es válido.

Comment: puedes añadir el error editando tu pregunta puedes ver el editar, pulsas y accedes luego buscas un lugar donde agregar el texto y guardas, bienvenido y quizas quieras leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos

Comment: El error es simple guardo una imagen en una base de datos ? Convirtiéndola de la siguiente manera MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); luego en mi picturebox le pasó el siguiente parámetro picturebox.image.save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.jpeg); pero la quiero recuperar desde un datagrid el cual recorro las filas mediante un datarow usando un foreach y a cada textbox y le pasó el parámetro correspondiente también lo quiero hacer en mi picturebox.

Comment: Hola @ChristopherR.SantosCruz por favor incluye toda la información necesara en la pregunta incluyendo, mensajes de error, código, cual es el resultado esperado e incluso la misma pregunta en sí que ni siquiera esta claro cual es. De lo contrario podría ser cerrado como "no está claro lo que se pregunta"

Answer (score 1):

Viendo el codigo de la imagen recomendaria que uses parametros, concatenar en un string los valores no es una buena practica.

Tu codigo deberia tener la estructura

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>"))  
{  
   conn.Open();  

   string query = "INSERT INTO NombreTabla (campo1, campo2) VALUES (@param1, @param2)";  
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);  
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Convert.ToString(TextBox1.Text));  
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", Convert.ToInt32(Textbox2.Text));  

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

}
```

Como veras no se concatenan los valores del INSERT o UPDATE, sino que se asignan a la lista de Parameters, esa es la forma en que deberia lucir tu codigo

Te dejo un artículo en donde explico como podrias hacer esto que comento

[[WinForms] Edición Empleados – Grabar imagen en base de datos](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/02/winforms-edicion-empleados-grabar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso una utilidad como esta

```
public class ImageHelper
{
    public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        return Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

    public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

}
```

Entonces si tienes el array de byte seria

```
byte[] datos = (byte[])row[campo imagen];
Picturebox1.Image =ImageHelper.ByteArrayToImage(datos);
```

Comment: Me da un error que me dice que el parámetro no es válido.

Comment: Analizando el codigo que nos estas mostrando no puedo determinar porque se podria generar este mensaje de error. Estas seguro que se produce al convertir el byte[] a Image? o es un error previo cuando asignas los parametros al SqlCommand cuando ejecutas la query. Puedes determinar en que linea se genera el error?

Comment: El error se genera cuando le pasó los parámetros a mi picturebox me dice que el método byteArrayToImage que el parámetro que devuelve no es válido !

Comment: Estoy usando un foreach para recorrer mi datagrid con él datarow para pasarle los parámetros a mis textbox etc. Cuando le pasó el parámetro al picturebox dentro del foreach. Dentro de mi foreach quiero llenar mi picturebox de la manera que lleno mis textbox pasándole el row[nombrecampo];